# Syntax error. Javascript function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a syntax error in my code. I have a PHP foreach loop inside a javascript function and trying to make it work but now it's says my whole function is not defined.

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button" onclick="addNewField(this)">


function addNewField()
 {
    <?php foreach($result as $data){
    $chain = $data['Access'];
    ?> 
      var element = $(<tr>
      <td><select class='selectpicker NameSelected'><option><<?php echo $chain; ?>></option></select></td>
      <td><input type='text'></td>
      <td><input type='text'></td>
      </tr>);
      $('.addNewRow').append(element);
    <?php

 }
 ?>
}
```

Comment: Which function? Presumably `addNewField()`? In which case, please show us the code you're calling this from.

Comment: `var element = $(<tr>`?

Comment: @j08691 I am inserting a new table row when I click the button

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited the question. But I believe that the error is in my function as my php and java script is not properly coded

Comment: @samscoot - You cannot run PHP code in the browser to add a new table row with a button click.

Comment: @RandyCasburn any other approach to do this?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I need to insert new rows to a table with a click of a button which I can easily do but I also need a select option in one of the column in the row and the values of that select option should come from my DB so that's why I need a php foreach loop

Comment: Replace the PHP code with Javascript code that accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: In that case (selection option from DB), you'll need to make a request to the server using Javascript, then have your PHP script return the option data, finally, populate the option with the data from the server. There are many examples of this around the web.

Comment: @RandyCasburn can you please provide me an working example.

Comment: @samscoot - have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

Comment: @RandyCasburn I got it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created gist for you: https://gist.github.com/meidikawardana/dd5c00b7cf894b025a6d66438381626e

your main mistake is you confusing between element and string data type in this part:

```
  var element = $(<tr>
  <td><select class='selectpicker NameSelected'><option><<?php echo $chain; ?>></option></select></td>
  <td><input type='text'></td>
  <td><input type='text'></td>
  </tr>);
```

it should be like this:

```
var element = "<tr>"
    +"<td><select class='selectpicker NameSelected' style='width:200px'><option><?php echo $chain; ?></option></select></td>"
    +"<td><input type='text'></td>"
    +"<td><input type='text'></td>"
    +"</tr>";
```